# How to auto create new hosts in Logentries for AWS EC2 autoscaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, logentries

What's the best way to send logs from Auto scaling groups (of EC2) to Logentries.

I previously used the EC2 platform to create EC2 log monitoring for all of my EC2 instances created by an Autoscaling group. However according to Autoscaling rules, new instance will spin up if a current one is destroyed.

Now how do I create an automation for Logentries to create a new hosts and starting getting logs. I've read this https://logentries.com/doc/linux-agent-with-chef/#updating-le-agent I'm stuck at the `override['le']['pull-server-side-config'] = false` since I don't know anything about Chef (I just took the training from their site)

Comment: Why not use the [Linux Agent - Autoscaling](https://logentries.com/doc/linux-agent-autoscaling/) format?

Comment: @James So where should I install this linux agent? Is it gonna be on my local linux machine or each of the EC2? I don't get how would the "agent" know if there is a new EC2 instance created on AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an Autoscaling group, you need to get this baked into an AMI, or scripted to run on startup.  You can get an [EC2 instance to run commands on startup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html), after you've figured out which script to run.

The Logentries [Linux Agent installation docs](https://logentries.com/doc/linux-agent/) has setup instructions for an Amazon AMI (under Installation > Select your distro below > Amazon AMI).

> Run the following commands one by one in your terminal:
>
> You will need to provide your Logentries credentials to link the agent to your account.

```
sudo -s
tee /etc/yum.repos.d/logentries.repo <<EOF
[logentries]
name=Logentries repo
enabled=1
metadata_expire=1d
baseurl=http://rep.logentries.com/amazon\$releasever/\$basearch
gpgkey=http://rep.logentries.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-logentries
EOF
yum update
yum install logentries
le register
yum install logentries-daemon
```

I recommend trying that script once and seeing if it works properly for you, then you could include it in the user data for your Autoscaling launch configuration.

Comment: Thanks, but when and where does "Linux Agent - Autoscaling" come in?

Comment: After you figure out how to configure the agent for one instance :)

Comment: the link to `baseurl` from your script don't work, what are those anyway?

Comment: It's the configuration for Logentries' Yum repo, so the `yum install logentries` command below will work.

Comment: Now I just need to rewrite this script so it won't prompt for any input during installation... and also, do you happen to know if I can run a script before an instance terminates (I want to remove that host on Logentries when an instance is terminated)

Comment: Also, when I use the autoscaling script, it does put my logs together, however I still see the hosts from each EC2 instance being generated on Logentries, how do I prevent that? I mean, all I need is to aggregate all the logs into 1 log set.

Comment: Are they grouped together under a "Log Set"?  It should be possible to query events across the set, but see individual hosts if there are problems particular to just that host.

Comment: Looking at their [autoscaling set up doc again](https://logentries.com/doc/linux-agent-autoscaling/), this is controlled by the `destination = MyLogSet/MyLog` in the config file, `/etc/le/config`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90934/discussion-between-casper-and-james).